# Error: Not a URL, existing file, or requirement spec:

Tags: python, windows, installation, psycopg2, easy-install

I'm trying to follow the tutorial at http://webdevon.com/setting-up-a-portable-postgresql-server-to-carry-on-an-usb-stick/ to install psycopg2 by following these instructions:

```
Go on this page to download it: http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/
Download the .exe of the right version you need
Install it via:
easy_install /path/to/the/file/psycopg2-2.4.4.win32-py2.7-pg9.1.2-release.exe
```

on my usb f: drive , inside my projects virtualenv, when I perform:

```
$ easy_install f:/psycopg2-2.5.1.win32-py2.7-pg9.2.4-release.
```

I get:

```
error: Not a URL, existing file, or requirement spec: 'f:/psycopg2-2.5.1.win32-p
y2.7-pg9.2.4-release'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to put the extension. Make sure the filename is specified *exactly* as it is on the disk.